# use Joomla 3.0 project on intranet

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 3.0 and i want to when user open joomla 3.0 site then first open only login page then after login he can access website.

Thanks For Advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: try reading the documentation http://docs.joomla.org/

Comment: How about having a look at SSO?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the site in offline mode.
So the site will display the login page.

Remember to grant permissions to the users to access the offline site!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "protect" the whole site with login the best option is to turn the site off and then the user will need to login after opening the intranet page. Its probably the cleanest way how to to it without modules/plugins.

As we are doing it in my company (we are also running intranet on Joomla!) is, that all the articles are set to registred and the landing page of intranet just contain warm welcome and login form.

One thing to mention: Forcing this login for viewing some article/other content is not secure at all, mostly the local instalation will run on database with root access without pass (default setting) and with unecrypted database easily accessible. This is something to consider. If you are running this intranet in small company with loyal employees or without sensitive information you should be fine if not you should put more stress on the security issues.